# Creating NSAttributedString on background queue: "[NSCell init] must be used from main thread only"

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment, nscell

I have a Cocoa app based on NSDocument that presents text documents to the user. Document contents are read on a background queue, which causes a problem:

I use `NSAttributedString` with images, i.e. it can contain `NSTextAttachment` and `NSTextAttachmentCell`. When I try to initialize an attachment for an image and I have the main thread checker activated in Xcode, I get the following error:

```
// On background queue:
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.attachmentCell = NSTextAttachmentCell(imageCell: image) <-

"[NSCell init] must be used from main thread only"
```

My first attempt was to wrap that code in `DispatchQueue.main.sync {}`, but this caused a deadlock with `NSDocument` once in a while when autosaving took place or when the user saved the document.

Autosaving would block the main queue, my code would run in the background trying to read the document, but this ended up in a deadlock, because I could not call out to the main queue to create the text attachment.

My question:

Is it possible for me to ignore the main thread checker in Xcode and instantiate `NSTextAttachmentCell` on a background queue anyway?

All I'm doing on the background queue is initializing the attributed string with its attachments. Further modifications are made on the main queue.

**Sequence of events**

1. **Thread 2 (bg queue)**: Need to update abc.txt for some reason. Get read/write access to abc.txt via `NSFileCoordinator`

   - *Thread 2 (bg) now in NSFileCoordinator block*
2. **Thread 1 (MAIN)**: User-initiated NSDocument save, NSDocument requests write access to abc.txt via `NSFileCoordinator`

   - *Thread 1 (MAIN) now blocked, waiting for file coordinator lock of Thread 2*
3. **Thread 2 (bg queue)**: Moving along in file coordinator block..., trying to initialize NSAttributedString, oh, it contains an attachment, can't initialize `NSTextAttachmentCell` on background queue, let me hand this off to the MAIN queue real' quick... ⚡️ DEADLOCK ⚡️

   - *Thread 2 (bg) is now waiting for Thread 1 (MAIN), which is waiting in front of its file coordinator access block for Thread 2 (bg) to finish with its file coordinator block.*

Comment: Im not an expert but can the document write on a background queue?

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore the main thread warnings. If you use `main.async` rather than `sync` there should never be an issue with adding the attachment. [This reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) also helps out defining which classes behave well in different threads. Generally speaking, any AppKit view type class should only be used on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did manage to produce a deadlock, even with `main.async` when using file coordination: (1) my background operation obtains a read/write lock on the file using file coordination and starts to read the file, (2) NSDocument begins an auto-save also using file coordination and blocks the main queue, (3) on my background queue, my code tries to instantiate the `NSAttributedString` with the attachment cell by offloading that to the (blocked) main queue. Not sure how to solve this...

Comment: Does the NSDocument auto-save block the main queue forever? #3 sounds irrelevant to the problem. Maybe this is a case for trying to avoid the autosave functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161308/prevent-nsdocuments-auto-saving-while-its-content-is-editing

Comment: Yes, NSDocument saving causes a deadlock with my background queue and hence locks the main queue forever. Disabling auto-save is not an option, unfortunately. I added a few Thread.sleep() at the right places to reproduce this reliably and noticed that a user-save via Cmd-S causes the same problem. The core issue is that both, NSDocument and my background operation, use NSFileCoordinator to get read/write access to the file and then the background operation is forced to reach out to the (NSDocument-blocked) main queue in order to initiate the NSTextAttachmentCell.

Comment: I added the exact sequence of events to the question.